# Man of the Match award for two players

Tags: cricket, history, icc, awards

Is it possible to give player of the match award to more than one player, when the stats and performances of more than one player (from the same team) equals the same?

If yes, any history for the above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the question is about sharing the player of the match award between two players from same team, here is the example for that in an international match.

Sunil Gavaskar and Chetan Sharma shared the "Man of the match" award in World Cup 87.
[Scorecard of the match.](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/65114.html)

Answer (score 14):

There are several occasions where man of the match award has been shared by two players

1. Ravi Bopara and Suresh Raina :
   http://crickethighlights.com/2011/09/suresh-raina-and-ravi-bopara-joint-men-of-the-match-ind-vs-eng-odi-4th/
2. Muralitharan and Ashraful : [www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/image/187690.html](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/image/187690.html)

Comment: I have deleted Atif Maqbool (Karachi Dolphins) and Shahzaib Hasan (Karachi Dolphins) answer as Domestic cricket leagues like IPL,BPL,SLPL BIG BASH etc are not recognized by ICC

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**, it's possible to share the Man of the Match award between two players of the same team.

In a day/night 20-over domestic match between Lahore Eagles vs Karachi Dolphins on 4th December 2012, the man of the match award was given to **Atif Maqbool (Karachi Dolphins) and Shahzaib Hasan (Karachi Dolphins)**.
[Source](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/594131.html)

Answer (score 7):

Martin guptill and Tom Latham  get joint man of the match award for a record partnership in 2015 in harare in Zimbabwe  on 04 Aug 2015 for the runs 236 and winning Newzeland by 10 wicket

-[Reference](http://www.espncricinfo.com/zimbabwe-south-africa-v-new-zealand-2015/engine/match/894289.html)

Answer (score 5):

This has occurred in the match between Australia and South Africa. On 12 March 2006, Played at **New Wanderers Stadium, Johannesburg**

HH Gibbs (South Africa) and RT Ponting (Australia) were name the players of the match.

Referred from [Espncricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/238200.html).

Answer (score 2):

In January 1999, all the eleven players of the team got player of the match award in a test match between WestIndies and SouthAfrica.

[Match Scorecard.](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/63823.html)

[image]

Comment: @SportsFan Scorecard is [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/63823.html); the [match report](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdenalmanack/content/story/153414.html) makes it clear that the award was actually to "the South African team" rather than the 11 players.