# Declaring Man of The Match and Man of the Series/Tournament Award

Tags: rules, cricket, awards

> Who holds the decision to declare Man of the Match/Man of the Series/
>   Tournament award?

Some [sources](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071017054456AAnmqyO) say that it is decided by commentators and former cricket players.

> How the Man of the match is decide when there are equivalent
>   performance from two players in the same match ?

a case in which a batsmen scores 100 runs with a good strike rate and a bowler takes a 5 wicket haul with an average economy rate.

> What will be things considered while declaring a Man of the Match for
>   such case ?

I know it is possible to [Award two man of the match](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/man-of-the-match-award-for-two-players). But how it is decided in other matches where there is only single man of the match award given.Any ICC rule for such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Who holds the decision to declare Man of the Match/Man of the Series/ Tournament award?

It depends on the tournament or series that is going on. In some series they are decided by commentators as they say while giving award as it was quite difficult for us to choose. But For the Big tournaments such as World Cup there is always a panel selected for decision taking.

> How the Man of the match is decide when there are equivalent performance from two players in the same match ?

It depends on which performance lead to match winning and at crucial time of the game.

> What will be things considered while declaring a Man of the Match for such case ?

I am not sure about if there is some rule as such but it is completely dependent on the performance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> Who holds the decision to declare Man of the Match/Man of the Series/ Tournament award?

In most cases, the panel of TV pundits and commentators chosen for the series act as the jury.

> How the Man of the match is decide when there are equivalent performance from two players in the same match ?

Generally, preference is given to the best match-winning effort, but there have been a number of awardees from the losing side too, by virtue of an extraordinary one-man role. Sometimes, the fielding accomplishments of the players are also considered. Joint winners have also been selected, like  HH Gibbs and RT Ponting in the  ["greatest game ever"](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/238200.html)  in 2006 between Australia and South Africa. Thus, there are **no ICC rules** in this regard and the decision is purely subjective.