# Man of the series award for two players

Tags: cricket, history, awards

I read a post about sharing the [man of the match award between two players](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/man-of-the-match-award-for-two-players).

Is there any instance happened in cricket history that the player of the series award got shared?

If yes, please provide the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The man of the Series was given to Yuvraj Singh and Graeme Smith jointly in India vs South Africa ODI series held in india 2005/06.

[Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_cricket_team_in_India_in_2005%E2%80%9306).

[Scorecard for the final match of that series](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/226359.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Test matches, this happened in the [controversial](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-pakistan-2010/content/story/474890.html) series between [England and Pakistan](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/426416.html) in which Mohammad Amir (Pakistan) and IJL Trott (England) were declared joint Man of the Series.

Answer (score 1):

The man of the Series was given to JM Anderson (England) and AD Mathews (Sri Lanka) jointly in England Vs SriLanka Test series held in England 2014.

[Scorecard for the final match of that series.](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-sri-lanka-2014/engine/match/667901.html)

Comment: I think it might be ECB's rule to declare MOS of both teams as the case in [my answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4377/540) is also for England in England.

Comment: @hims056, i'm not understand what you are saying?

Comment: Check any team's tour to England. You will find that they declare two man of the series in *every* series (at least for last 10 year).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to above list we have one more series with shared Man of the Series Award.
In the recent series between India and England - Man of the series award was shared between James Anderson and B Kumar.

Source: https://cricket.yahoo.com/postmatch-england-vs-india_187257#England 1st Innings

[image: https://cricket.yahoo.com/postmatch-england-vs-india_187257#England 1st Innings]

Comment: Yeh [as I said](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/man-of-the-series-award-for-two-players#comment11553_5061) this always happens in England.

Comment: Yes They seem to be doing same:)