# Man of the series award for two players from same team

Tags: cricket, trivia, history, awards

From [this post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/man-of-the-series-award-for-two-players), it's clear that more than one player can get the player of the series award in cricket.

From [this post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/man-of-the-match-award-for-two-players), it's clear that more than one player can get the player of the match award that too from the same team.

I have a query that,
Is there any instance in the history of cricket that more than one player **from the same team** got the man of the series award?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the tag "*performance*". That tag is relating to the physical, mental, emotional performance not the overall performance (e.g. batting performance or bowling performance) in the match.

Comment: @hims056, removed that tag. Does the tag `officiating` suit this post?

Comment: There is no rule at all in the question. It's just a trivia and history question IMO.

Comment: @hims056, I think batting performance or bowling performance will come under physical performance :)

Comment: Okay I have added [a question on Meta](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/527/540). Let's see what others think. If it is okay then I will try to edit the excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having researched, I can not find any instance where man of the series has been awarded to two players from the same team, there have been instances of the single award being shared as described in the top link you provide.

Where there is a seperate award for each team I have been unable to find any sharing.